# forecast stock levels based on client demand using Machine learning

Tags: xgboost, arima, facebook-prophet

I hope everything is good with you.
In order to investigate fertilizer sales over time, I require the assistance of a master of data science who can work with time series machine learning (ARIMA, AUTO-aRIMA, FBprophet, and XGboost).

I'm trying to achieve that, but I believe I'm making a lot of errors.
My objectives are to forecast stock levels based on client demand.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMkAo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzbrk.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2dXC.png)

Using machine learning (ARIMA, AUTO-aRIMA, FBprophet, and XGboost)